# Powershell command does not work when application is published

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line, publish

So i made an application with multiple Powershell commands. They work perfectly when i run it through Visual Studio, but when i publish the application and run the .exe then for some reason the commands dont work, even on my pc and they give me errors i have tried changing the command itself but whatever command i type i keep getting the error from powershell.

```
// These are 2 of the commands i use
Get-LocalUser -Name Almar
Get-LocalUser -Name Almar.Description

// I run them using a Process function
Process cmd2 = new Process();
                    cmd2.StartInfo.FileName = $@"powershell ";
                    cmd2.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"Get-LocalUser -Name Almar.Description";
                    cmd2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    cmd2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    cmd2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    cmd2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    cmd2.Start();
                    cmd2.WaitForExit();
                    StreamReader reader = cmd2.StandardOutput;
                    string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Even when i open a Command prompt or a powershell these commands work, only when i publish it and run it as an .exe it gives me errors.

> Here's a screenshot of my publishing settings
> [image: screenshot1]

> Here's a screenshot of when i try to run the published .exe
> [image: screenshot2]

As i said in the beginning, when i run the application in Visual Studio all the commands work but for some reason when the .exe is ran it just gives me errors.

If anyone know's why this is or did i mess something up while publishing please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried adding `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts;` before calling `Get-LocalUser`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts;` but with no succes [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFXrT.png) is the error i got.